# Deletar dados da tabela quando atingir um determinado numero

Tags: php, mysql

Fala galera!

Tenho uma tabela chamada tb_chat com os campos id_mensagem,nome,mensagem,data,hora.

como deleto os dados dessa tabela quando atingir '6' registros?

Answer (score 0):

Como não é possível executar um delete usando a mesma tabela em uma subquery, você deverá fazer isso em duas etapas:

Primeiro, você pode selecionar o primeiro item da tabela tb_chat com base na quantidade de registros. Isso pode ser feito de várias formas, ex:

2. SELECT MIN(id_mensagem) FROM tb_chat HAVING COUNT(id_mensagem) > 6
3. SELECT id_mensagem FROM tb_chat HAVING COUNT(id_mensagem) > 6 ORDER BY id_mensagem ASC LIMIT 1

Depois disso, basta executar o delete com o ID retornado da consulta (se a consulta não retornar nenhum registro, não há mais que 6 itens na tabela)